# Tensorflow ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. Min Max Scaling

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn

```
    png = tf.read_file(filename)
    image = tf.image.decode_png(png, dtype=tf.uint16, channels=1)
    scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
    scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(image)
    depth = tf.cast(depth, tf.float32)
```

The images are read from a csv file.I want to normalize the data.
The above method throws an error.
Can someone tell me how do I apply the scikit learn MinMax scaling on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
image = tf.div(
        tf.subtract(
            image,
            tf.reduce_min(image)
            ),
        tf.subtract(
            tf.reduce_max(image),
            tf.reduce_min(image)
            )
        )
```